# I am reading an excel file in pandas but it is throwing an syntax error

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I imported pandas using the terminal and imported my absolute file path and wrote the code as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("file path")
print(df)
```

I got a syntax error like the following

(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Can you attach an example of your file path?

Comment: C:\\Users\\manis\\onedrive\\docs\\file_name

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on windows?

The file path in Windows uses `\`, and because of this, the file path may not be recognized properly.

use like this
`path = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\file.xls'`

---

[image]

next time, please add in your question.

It says pandas is not installed

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

Please read the above document and proceed with the installation.

Comment: I have used it and it is throwing me Module not found error

Comment: Please attach the full error message.

Comment: I have added it in the question please check it

Answer (score -1):

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 2-3

For your original problem, the first backslash in your string is being interpreted as a special character.

You can use these two ways to edit your path:

```
df = pd.read_excel("C\\Users\\manis\\onedrive\\docs\\file_name")
```

or

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"C\Users\manis\onedrive\docs\file_name")
```

For your additional issue about ModuleNotFound.

Please choose the correct `python interpreter` and then choose the `jupyter kernel` which you have installed the python package in.

Use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python environment.

Click the button in jupyter-notebook to choose the kernel.

[image]

This can solve your **ModuleNotFound** error.

Comment: _how_ does that solve the problem? what was the cause and how does this address it?

Comment: I provide a response to the question that op added to the Giuk Kim's answer. For the initial question, I think his answer is sufficient.

Comment: that's not how Q&A here is supposed to work. follow up questions should either be edits to the question post, or asked as separate questions. answers should be answers to the question as asked in the question post. as you've stated, this isn't an answer to the question post- it's an answer to a follow up question asked in comments under an answer post. this is not a forum. please delete this. If you want to solve that problem of the asker's, use the comments or use chat.